# How to identify unicode keys on key press?

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009

My application uses unicode characters and i have several text fields where i want to restrict user from inputing special characters like **:'";**

```
begin
    if not (Key in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z',' ','0'..'9',#13,#8]) then
        Key := #0;
    if Key = #13 then
        bOk.Click;
end;
```

So at this point it lets user add spaces and use a backspace key to erase, and of course Enter key to comfirm.

There are few unicode characters i want to let being inputed also.
ą, č, ė, į, š, ų, ū, ž
and their uppercase alternatives, but just adding them to the set like so...

```
Key in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z',' ','0'..'9',#13,#8,'ą'..'ž','Ą'..'Ž']
```

... does nothing and i still can not write these symbols in the text field.

I would like to know, how to fix this problem. Is there a way to tell if the pressed key is the unicode character i'm looking for?

Thank you

Comment: Note that you should generally use `CharInSet` in D2009. The compiler warns you about that. `CharInSet` does only work for ANSI character sets though. utku_karatas answers is the way to go.

Comment: +1 @Smasher: just make that an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're on D2009 or later there's a unit named **Character** containing functions like **IsLetterOrDigit**, **IsLetter**, etc. all handling specifically what you need.

Comment: Thank you, i have read help file on 'Character' and it solved my problem. I have changed my 'if' statement like so: 'if not IsLetterOrDigit(Key) and not CharInSet(Key,[#8,#13,' ']) then'.

Answer (score 4):

**Please pay attention to Hints and Warnings when you compile your apps. To ignore them is to ignore potential problems**.

You should be getting warning that "WideChar is reduced to byte char...". Therein lies the problem: the `Key` is no longer Unicode in your set operation!

The warning advises you to use `CharInSet`; you can also look at `TCharacter` (a special class with class functions to identify certain categories of characters). If neither of these suit your requirements, then use a string constant with all the *valid* characters, and use the `Pos` function to determine if the `Key` is present.

Finally, you may rather want to consider excluding specific characters as opposed to trying to think of every specific character you want to include.

Comment: Very helpful answer too. Thank you. String with specific characters and Pos function is very handy in cases where i want to let or restrict to write certain characters.